# Why do paintbrush loops get thicker at the top in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, illustrator-effects

When I do swirls in Illustrator with the paintbrush tool I often get this result (see image).

[image: Loops get cut off in illustrator]

The loops doesn't get perfectly rounded, instead sometimes some of them gets thicker at the top of the loop... It tends to happen more if I paint small with low brush sizes. Why is this happening?

Comment: As you've discovered.. draw bigger. You're swirls are too tight and the brush geometry can't navigate the curves. Either create swirls first, then apply a brush stroke, or create larger art for the brush to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i found a solution to this. Edit the "5 pt round brush" (by double clicking it), change "Size" to something low like 0,5 pt. Save the new brush and edit stroke size to 2 pt. This solved the problem for me, hope it helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

After drawing your swirl, select it and change the Brush Definition from the default (2pt Oval or whatever you are using) to 'Basic', also make sure your Variable Width Profile is set to 'Uniform'.[image: screenshot of toolbar]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I always use Uniform and the problem is the same even if i choose Basic or Oval in the Brush Definitions.

Comment: The trick is to highlight your swirl and change it to Basic _after_ it is drawn.

Comment: "Basic" is **NOT** a brush -- common misconception because of where Adobe put it. But "Basic" means "Remove brush stroke"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening when I used "pressure" setting on my WACOM tablet. To fix the issue, you go to your "appearance" panel and select the stroke category. Under that you will see "Cap" "Corner" and "Align Stroke" .. my "Corner" option was set to 10 px.. When I changed it to 1 the issue stopped happening. :-)